# CSS Selector (if not null) + nested

Tags: html, css, nested, css-selectors

I am searching for something like

```
.class[height!= "0"] .span
```

Every time i try to nest something like

`div.item.class[height="0"]`  it didn't work.

Maybe someone can help me? :)

Here is more Code:

HTML

```
<div class="barWrapper">
                                        <ul id ="tabs" class="nav-bar" data-tabs="tabs">
                                            <li class="speed" style="height: 0%;"><a href="#Riesenslalom" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a></li>
                                            <li class="speed" style="height: 0%;"><a href="#Speed" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a></li>
                                            <li class="mixrace act" style="height: 100%;"><a href="#Mix_Race" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a><em>1056</em></li>
                                            <li class="mixrace act" style="height: 5%"><a href="#Freeride" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a><em>5</em></li>
                                            <li class="mixrace act" style="height: 70%"><a href="#Foto_Rallye" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a><em>539</em></li>
                                            <li class="mixrace act" style="height: 10%"><a href="#Slalom" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a><em>20</em></li>
                                            <li class="speed" style="height: 0%"><a href="#Buckelpiste" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a></li>
                                            <li class="speed" style="height: 0%;"><a href="#Flug" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a></li>
                                            <li class="mixrace act" style="height: 90%"><a href="#Carving" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a><em>800</em></li>
                                            <li class="mixrace act" style="height: 100%"><a href="#Wandern" data-toggle="tab"><span></span></a><em>1200</em></li>
                                            <li id="line"></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                    </div>
```

CSS

```
div.item.topStatistic .topStatistic-content .first .left .statisticWrapper .barWrapper ul > li span{position:absolute; bottom:0; width: 100%; height:40px; text-align: center; }
div.item.topStatistic .topStatistic-content .first .left .statisticWrapper .barWrapper ul > .speed span{background: url("icon_statistic_Speed.png") no-repeat transparent;}
div.item.topStatistic .topStatistic-content .first .left .statisticWrapper .barWrapper ul > .mixrace:not([height=0]) span{background: url("icon_statistic_active_MixRace.png") no-repeat transparent;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css has `:not()` as a pseudo selector. So `.class:not([height=0])` should work.
http://caniuse.com/#search=:not

Comment: thanks, but there is still an error. Here is my code:                   <li class="race act" style="height:10%"><a href="#race"><span></span></a><em>20</em></li>   .statisticWrapper .barWrapper ul > .race:not([height=0]) span{background: url("icon_statistic_active_Race.png") no-repeat transparent;}

Comment: [height=0] searches for <div height="0"> not the css in style=""

Comment: You are looking for a way to "if" in css, this is not possible. You should take another way of getting what you want, this is not the way to go. What do you want to do with the divs that have 0 height?

Comment: how are you selecting height:0 may i ask? :)

Comment: i use .class:not([style="height:0;"])  :)

Comment: haha, nice. Pretty specific, but if it's always this specific, why not! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo element it will work for you but problem is that, It only work with major browser not in ie8 and blow

> `:not()`

Comment: thanks, but there is still a problem. maybe you can check the new code in my question?